# How To Automatically Logon To Windows 7 using a Password

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop, kiosk

I am working on a Kiosk Application based on Windows 7 Ultimate.

I need:

- connect to the kiosk using Remote Desktop Connection (so UserName and
  Passwprd seems required).
- enable auto login for the kiosk.

Any idea how to achieve these features?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was

Autologon for Windows
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx

Which enable to automatically login a user using his password

I would also suggest, in order to set Windows configuration for a Kiosk
KIOSK Classic
http://sourceforge.net/projects/kioskclassic/

Answer (score 4):

It seems you already have your answers, but I'll add something for future readers.  This powershell snip allows for auto-logon via the registry.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultUserName -Value "Administrator"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultPassword -Value "Password"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name ForceAutoLogon -Value 1
```

or can be done the old fashioned way.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"DefaultUserName"="Administrator"
"DefaultPassword"="Password"
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy that to notepad, edit, and save it as a bat file. Run on the destination

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName  /t REG_SZ /d "User" /f

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword  /t REG_SZ /d "Password" /f

reg delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoLogonCount /f

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v ForceUnlockLogon  /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d "domain"
```

1. If you do not have a domain just use `.\`
2. If you want to set a number for the AutoLogonCount, it's decreased on every reboot. Once reached 0, it will stop autologon and reset all your registry keys.