# Powershell set-itemproperty doesn't change registry setting

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a script that I run to lockdown a windows 7 computer to run a VM Client when booted.
when it runs it creates the local user account that is going to be used for logging in
Checks for the DefaultPassword  reg key and if is not there creates the key

It sets the registry values for
AutoAdminLogon value to 1
DefaultdomainName value to the local machine name
DefaultPassword value to the local user account password
DefaultUsername value to the local user that was setup in the script
ForceAutoLogon value to 1
LogonType value to 0

After this is done the computer reboots and should login as the local user automatically
but it doesn't.  I've check the keys and prior to the reboot everything is correct.  But after reboot its back to what it was before the script was run.

The weird thing is .. if I run the script again .. everything works.

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening???

As I said if I run the same script again AFTER the reboot it set the registry entries with no problems and they stay after the 2nd reboot. So I'm thinking there something going on after the first reboot .. my first thoughts where Domain Group Policies but if that was the case then I would get the same results on the 2nd run of the script and reboot.  I have another script that I run after this one that sets the local user startup to launch the VMClient and disables taskmanager , lockworkstation, and change password functions when they use ctlr-alt-del keys, which is done in the registry .. this work just fine.

Comment: workaround could be to use a ps1 startup script (gpedit.msc). Using the machine startup folder so that it runs before the logon screen appears.  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379759/how-to-automatically-logon-to-windows-7-using-a-password/21395736#21395736

Answer (score 0):

My instinct says that it's a feature of ForceAutoLogon, rather than a problem with PowerShell's Set-ItemProperty.

[ForceAutoLogon Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/06/544496.aspx)

Extract:

"In addition to logging on an account automatically, the ForceAutoLogon setting also logs you back on after you log off.

Setting the ForceAutoLogon setting effectively locks out all users aside from the one you are forcing."

Comment: If I set that to 0 and have the autoadminlogin set to 1 would the computer still log in as the "USER"?

Comment: Just tried setting the forceautologon to zero .. did not fix issue .. but thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

After search and search for a resolution to my problem I finally found the issue.
One of the Forums I check mentions the AUTOLOGONCOUNT reg key .. when I looked at my computer it was not there.. after I had rebooted the computer .... This is a Corporate Computer and we use MDT to reimage the computers ... so it does autologon a couple of times.  Which when it is done the count is set to zero and the autologon is set to zero .. but the  AUTOLOGONCOUNT reg key  is still there. so when I ran my script it would set it and at reboot .. unset it .. DUH me LOL .. any I re-image a computer and delete this key and ran my powershell script and all is good

thanks for those that gave me ideas